# How to serialize an object with newtonsoft, which has a value with backslash [\]

Tags: vb.net, serialization, json.net

I prepared this small example to show you my problem (vb.net and  Newtonsoft)

**I would prefer that the solution be done with Newtonsoft.**

```
    Public Class Message
        Property Emoji As String
    End Class


    Public Sub GetJson()

        Dim msgObject As New Message With {.Emoji = "\uD83D\uDE00"}

        'Option 1
        Dim JsonSerializerSettings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
        Dim msgJson_1 As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgObject, JsonSerializerSettings)

        'Option 2
        Dim msgJson_2 As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)

        'Option 3
        Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter()
        Using writer As New JsonTextWriter(stringWriter)
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.None
            Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
            serializer.Serialize(writer, msgObject)
        End Using
        Dim msgJson_3 As String = stringWriter.ToString()

    End Sub
```

with none of the three options works, it always results in

```
{
    "Emoji": "\\uD83D\\uDE00"
}
```

The result I need is

```
{
    "Emoji": "\uD83D\uDE00"
}
```

How do I set Newtonsoft to not take into account the backslash character, as an escaped character?

Another unorthodox way could be:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\\","\")
```

I do not really like

Thanks!!!!

Comment: If you deserialize the value that is what you will get.

Answer (score 1):

\ is an escape char in JSON hence if you try and serialise a \ it gets escaped as \\ then when you deserialise \\ you get \

My guess is you have been given an example asking you to send `"Emoji": "\uD83D\uDE00"`

In json (and C#) `\u####` specifies a unicode character (usually for something not found on a keyboard) as you are using VB.NET instead you should use `$"{ChrW(&HD83D)}{ChrW(&HDE00)}`"

Comment: Thanks for your input, I read about "some magical way" to tell Newtonsoft to ignore the value of the \ character as escaped.

Another unorthodox way could be:

jsonString = jsonStrinf.replace("//","/")

I do not really like

Answer (score -1):

"jsonString = jsonString.replace("//","/") " will never work, this is more safe way

```
json = json.Replace("\\\\u","\\u");
```

or since you don't  like old, good classical solutions

```
json = Regex.Replace(json, @"\\u", @"u");
//or
json = json.Replace(@"\\u", @"\u");
```

even this will work in your case ( but I will not recommend for another cases since it is not safe)

```
json = Regex.Unescape(json);
```

Comment: The question is: "How do I set Newtonsoft to not take into account the backslash character, as an escaped character?". Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AAP You just put one extra backslash in several places. How Newtonsonft can decide is it  on pourpouse or not? This way Newtonsonft will change all text the way it likes